# Python program does not return missing values

Tags: python

I am trying to return all rows in the data where the description is missing but my code isn't working:

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```py
df[df["Description"].isna()]
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "missing"?  `None`?  `NaN`?  Zero?  Empty string?  No value at all?

Comment: The output that I am getting is : Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Invoice, StockCode, Description, Quantity, InvoiceDate, Price, Customer ID, Country]
Index: []

Answer (score 0):

If DF is a sort of list you'd be grabbing a `bool` from the frame. Something like `df[True]` which of course doesn't exist. You could use an inline for loop and a filter function to find all of the values that fulfill `.isna()`.

```
df = [{"description": "something"}, {"description": None}]

print(list(filter(lambda item: not item == None, [item if item["description"].isna() else None for item in df])))
```

You could also just make a simple loop for clearer code.

```
df = [{"description": "something"}, {"description": None}]
isna = []

for item in df:
    if item["description"].isna(): 
        isna.append(item)

print(isna)
```